# Can't FindControl when RenderControl ascx in RenderBeginTag while overriding Panel

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, overriding, findcontrol, webusercontrol

I'm creating a container using `Panel` control as follows:

```
public class CustomContainer : Panel
{
 public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
 {
  var control this.Page.LoadControl("web user control path.ascx");
  control.ID = "userControlId";
  control.RenderControl(writer);
  base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
 }
 public void ShowMessage(string message)
 {
  var control = this.FindControl("userControlId"); // control here is null!!
  var custom = control as CustomControl;
  custom.Message = message;
 }
}
```

when I try to find the control with id `userControlId` which I rendered, it always retuns null!
Does anyone know what's happening? How can I solve this issue?

BTW: I can't add the `CustomControl` in `CreateChildControls` method because if the `CustomContainer`  has code block I got an exception!

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling `ShowMessage` before the control is rendered. Try calling `ShowMessage` during `OnPreLoad` or `OnLoad`. Basically, anywhere after the `Render`.